# BigQuery load job failing with "Could not parse 'Text' as bool"

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Creating a table from a CSV file in Big Query with Auto Detect Schema.

Load job fails with the error:

> Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'good' as bool for field order_Flag (position 26) starting at location 1689438

Even though the column has some rows with text/string, why is BigQuery parsing it as a bool?

Comment: Can you please provide some example data to help troubleshoot this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Even though the column has some rows with text/string, **why is BigQuery parsing it as a bool**?

When auto-detection is enabled, BigQuery starts the inference process by scanning up to 100 rows of data in your file to use as a representative sample. BigQuery then examines each field and attempts to assign a data type to that field based on the values in the sample.

So, looks like those "some rows with text/string" are beyond 100 rows used for auto-detection and first 100 rows "define" that field as a Boolean

You can read more about [Schema auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect)

To avoid this  - you can define your own schema for the load - see details for [Loading CSV data into a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table)

Answer (score 0):

for this particular issue, uncheck Auto Schema, and in line 1 write "name:string, gender:srting, count:number"

Answer (score 0):

name:STRING,
gender:STRING,
count:NUMERIC

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What does this answer add more than [this also low quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72584946/16019058)